Solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x)\sin(2x)}{x^2+2x+2}dx$ with residue theorem
I am trying to solve following integral with resiude theorem: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(1+x)\sin(2x)}{x^2+2x+2}dx:=I.$$
There is a singularity at $-1+i$. Therefore we can find the residue using the following formula: $$Res(f, -1+i)= \lim_{x\to-1+i} \left[(x+1-i)\frac{(1+x)\sin(2x)}{(x+1-i)(x+1+i)}\right]=\lim_{x\to-1+i} \frac{(1+x)\sin(2x)}{x+1+i}=Im(e^{-2i-2}).$$ Here I used the fact that $\sin(2x)=Im(e^{2ix})$.
Thus I got the following solution for the Integral: $$I=2\pi i \cdot Res(f, -1+i)=  2 \pi i \cdot Im(\frac{e^{-2i-2}}{2}).$$ This is approximately $-0,06$.
However, when I type in this integral in Wolfram Alpha I get approximately $-0,18$, which isn't equivalent to the solution I got.
Did I do a mistake when solving this integral or could there be the possibility that this integral isn't holomorphic at all?

which path did you choose?

The answer is $\pi\cos(2)e^{-2}\approx-0.176932$.

i chose a semi-circle in the upper half-plane as a contour

Hint: use $z=x+1$ first then write the integral as $(\cos2\cdot\Im-\sin2\cdot\Re)\oint\frac{ze^{2iz}\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}$.

You have to consider that
$$\begin{align*}I &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1+x}{x^2+2x+2}\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}dx = \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1+x}{x^2+2x+2}\frac{e^{2ix}}{2i}dx- 
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1+x}{x^2+2x+2}\frac{e^{-2ix}}{2i}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1+x}{x^2+2x+2}\frac{e^{2ix}}{2i}dx -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1-y}{y^2-2y+2}\frac{e^{2iy}}{2i}dx \end{align*}$$
These are Fourier-type integrals, they can be evaluated using

Theorem Let $f$ be meromorphic on $\Bbb C$, having only a finite number of poles, not lying on the real axis. Suppose that there is a constant $K$ such that
$$ |f(z)|\leq \frac{K}{|z|}$$
for all sufficiently large $|z|$. Let $a>0$ then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) e^{iax} = 2\pi i \ \sum \text{residues of $e^{iaz}f(z)$ in the upper half plane.}$$

We are exactly in this situation with our integral so
$$I = 2\pi i \ [ \text{Res}_f(-1+i) - \text{Res}_g(1+i)] $$
where
$$f(z) = \frac{1+z}{z^2+2z+2}\frac{e^{2iz}}{2i}\\
g(z) = \frac{1-z}{z^2-2z+2}\frac{e^{2iz}}{2i}$$
after a little bit of residue evaluation we got
$$\begin{align*}I &= 2\pi i \ \bigg[-\frac{1}{4}ie^{-2}e^{-2i} -\frac{1}{4}ie^{-2}e^{2i}\bigg]\\
& = \pi e^{-2} \ \frac{e^{2i}+e^{-2i}}{2} = \frac{\pi}{e^2}\cos(2)
\end{align*}$$
As mentioned in the comment section.

I hope this helps!

Hint: Let $f:=\frac{e^{i 2z}}{\left(z^2+2z+2\right)/\left(z+1\right)}$ and $\Gamma:=[-R, R] \oplus S_R$, where $S_R=\{z:|z|=R, \arg z \in(0, \pi)\}$.
Then, your integral $I = \mathfrak{I} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(z) d z$.
You must also confirm it satisfies Jordan's Lemma on $S_R$.
